# Why are the margins not working correctly?

Tags: css

I want to achieve this:
[image]
I have achieved this:
[image]

Why are the margins set on #members-content-box not working correctly? The page is live at http://goo.gl/e7yiAf

```
<section id="members-content">
<div id="members-menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="members-my-items.html">My Items</a></li>
<li><a href="members-submit-items.html">Submit Items</a></li>
<li><a href="members-accounts-settings.html">Account Settings</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="menu-line">
</div>
</div>
<div id="members-content-box">
hello
<br /><br /><br />
</div>
</section>
```

My CSS:

```
/* members menu*/
#members-content { width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;}
#members-menu { width: 100%; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 30px;}
#members-menu ul { list-style: none;}
#members-menu li { background-color: #FFF; width: 127px; height: 25px; text-align: center; float: left; margin-right: 7px; padding-top: 8px}
#members-menu li a { font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; color: #2e2e2e; text-decoration: none;}
#members-menu li a:hover { color: #ffbe00;}
#members-menu li a:active { color: #ffbe00;}
#menu-line { height: 5px; background-color: #FFF; float:left; min-width: 100%; margin-left:0 40px 0 40px;}
/* members-content-box */
#members-content-box { background-color:#FFF; padding: 35px; float: left; width:100%; border: 1px solid grey;}
```

Comment: But you apply `padding` instead of `margin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use margin instead of padding - padding will just enlarge the div from inside including its background

```
#members-content-box { background-color:#FFF; margin: 35px; float: left; width:100%; border: 1px solid grey;}
```

Answer (score 0):

To Achieve the above one put the `padding-bottom` for `members-menu` `ul`

```
#members-menu{
padding-bottom:30px;
}
```

And change `members-content-box` css like this

```
#members-content-box {
background-color: #FFF;
padding: 35px;
float: left;
width: 90%;
border: 1px solid grey;
margin-left:30px;
}
```

I think this one helpful to you.